# Access VBA: On Form Open set Labels

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm not sure how to phrase this so i'll just talk through it. There are multiple forms open at one time. A user bounces between a few of them through buttons that navigate through the forms. I am trying to make the labels change dynamically as they bounce through forms. The code below works on a Click event...

```
Private Sub Command56_Click()
    Label21.Caption = Nz(Forms("User_Activities").text14.Value)
    Label22.Caption = Nz(Forms("User_Activities").text16.Value)
    Label23.Caption = Nz(Forms("User_Activities").text18.Value)
    Label24.Caption = Nz(Forms("User_Activities").text20.Value)
    Label25.Caption = Nz(Forms("User_Activities").text22.Value)
    Label26.Caption = Nz(Forms("User_Activities").text24.Value)
    Label27.Caption = Nz(Forms("User_Activities").text26.Value)
    Label28.Caption = Nz(Forms("User_Activities").text28.Value)
    Label29.Caption = Nz(Forms("User_Activities").text30.Value)
    Label30.Caption = Nz(Forms("User_Activities").text32.Value)
End Sub
```

I'm trying to figure out what to use instead of `Click` Here to make it dynamic. I've tried initialize, resize, and load. None of those work because the form is already open at the time.

Comment: Or use textboxes as 'labels' with expression in ControlSource property referencing the other form control. No VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out my problem. There were many ways to go about solving this, but the simplest was to use `Form_Activate()`

Comment: And exactly how did you use `Form.Activate`? Did you mean `Form_Activate()` event?

Comment: Ahh yes! I just noticed i'm missing the parenthesis